# What is the motivation behind this sampling algorithm

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, random-variable, order-statistics

I was recently reading on methods for sampling from linear distributions of directions. This distribution on a direction $X$ is defined by the density
$$
p(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1-3\kappa)+3\kappa\frac{1+x}{2}\quad \text{   for  } x\in[-1,1],
$$
indexed by the fixed parameter $0\le\kappa\le\frac{1}{3}$. 
T
his distribution is a mixture of two distributions. Therefore, one could do the sampling in stages. Define
$$
p_1=(1-3\kappa)
$$
and 
$$
p_2=3\kappa
$$
which allows us to write
$$
p(x)=p_1d_1(x)+p_2d_2(x)
$$

Either of the two probabilities can be selected using the probability mixing method. That is, for a pdf given by
$$
P(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^np_id_i(x)
$$

with
$$
1=\sum\limits_{i=1}^np_i
$$

generate uniform random number $r\in(0,1)$ and checking if
$$
r\in\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m-1}p_i, \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}p_i \right)
$$
before generating from $d_i$.

In this particular case the sum has only two summands.

What I don't understand is the implementation of the above method.  Consider the following python script

```
def sample(k0):
  k=abs(k0)
  r1=np.random.uniform()
  if r1<=(1.-3.*k):
      r2=np.random.uniform()
      # uniform sampling for the cosine in the range -1,1
      cos=2.*r2-1
  else:
  # what is the meaning of this part ?
      r2=np.random.uniform()
      r3=np.random.uniform()
      cos=2.*max(r2,r3)-1.
  return cos*k0/k   

# to plot & run use
k0=0.1
x=np.array([sample(k0) for x in range(1000000) ])

plt.hist(x,bins=100,normed=True)
plt.show()
```

But the meaning of the above lines of code used to sample the direction remains unclear:

```
  # what is the meaning of this part ?
      r2=np.random.uniform()
      r3=np.random.uniform()
      cos=2.*max(r2,r3)-1.
```

Why are two random uniforms and the max of them needed to sample the cosine?

I would be grateful if someone could explain this point.

Comment: @Xi'an the direction cosine $x$ is being sampled and the allowed values are $x\in[-1,1]$. $\kappa$ is just a constant. Thank you for the comment. I corrected the missing part from the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $U_1,U_2\sim\cal{U}(0,1)$, then
$$V=\max\{U_1,U_2\}\sim 2v\mathbb{I}_{(0,1)}(v)$$
and by a change of variable (with Jacobian $\frac{1}{2}$)
$$W=2V-1\sim \frac{1}{2} \{w+1\}\mathbb{I}_{(-1,1)}(w)$$
which is exactly the meaning of the code

```
  r2=np.random.uniform()
  r3=np.random.uniform()
  cos=2.*max(r2,r3)-1.
```

and it produces a simulation from the second part of the mixture density
$$d_2(x)=\frac{1+x}{2}\mathbb{I}_{(-1,1)}(x)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for editing/imporving the question. Reading your answer I was not able to understand the meaning of the second equation. Could you please explain it.

Comment: OK I get it now. $\left|\frac{v(w)}{dw}\right|\cdot 2v\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot2\cdot\frac{w+1}{2}*\mathbb{1}_{(-1,1})$ since $W\in[-1,1]$. Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry, I totally forgot.

Comment: I was reading again the book where this example comes from. They say that if the parameter $\kappa$ is negative, one can replace it by its absolute value $|\kappa|$ but multiply the value of the sampled 'x' by the sign of $\kappa$ i.e $x\cdot\frac{\kappa}{|\kappa|}$ or in the code `cos*k0/k`. Is there a theory behind that?

Comment: I am sorry I meant $k>\frac{1}{3}$